# Separate files for Ember handlebars templates in a Middleman App

Tags: ember.js, rack, sprockets, middleman

I have multiple Ember apps that live in a Middleman app. The current directory structure is

```
[app-name]
  components
  helpers
  source

  assets
    img
    css
    js
      // jQuery for other pages
      app.js

      // An ember app
      fullscreen
        components
        controllers
        models
        routes
        views
        app.js

      // Another ember app
      sandbox
        components
        controllers
        models
        routes
        views
        app.js

  demos
    // These currently contain the templates, in script tags
    fullscreen.erb
    sandbox.erb
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can move the templates out of the script tags. At this point, I've spent quite a bit of time trying to get various solutions to work:

- https://github.com/mrship/middleman-ember
- https://gist.github.com/GutenYe/4364010
- http://nerdyworm.com/blog/2013/05/06/ember-dot-js-and-middleman/

This last one I had working at some point, but can't get it working again now.

What's the simplest way to accomplish this? I am new to Sprockets and Rack, which is making this harder for me to sort through.

Answer (score 0):

Generelly its not hard to build this by yourself. U just need a JS runtime, compile the templates, and put them into Ember.TEMPLATES.
Have a look on [precompilation](http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html): and the [TEMPLATES Hash](http://emberjs.com/api/#property_TEMPLATES)